# Failed to establish ssh connection passwordless to run PVM codes

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, distributed-system, pvm

I tried to build **PVM** code. For that a ssh connection without password is required. I searched a lot and I found a tutorial , I implemented the same, but it didn't work.

**My work:-**

1. master is jhamb.
2. slave is naveen.
3. Firstly I generate ssh keys on master(jhamb), by using command

   ssh-keygen -t rsa
4. Then I copied id_rsa.pub file into slave(naveen) machine, by using command

   scp /home/jhamb/.ssh/id_rsa.pub  naveen@10.40.54.92:/home/naveen/.ssh/authorized_keys
5. Then I login into slave from master., by using

   ssh naveen@10.40.54.92
6. But it always asking for password.

Help me to solve this problem, then only I can configure further for PVM.

Looking for your kind response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the ssh version, you might have to do also this:

```
 - Put the public key in .ssh/authorized_keys2 
 - Change the permissions of .ssh to 700 
 - Change the permissions of .ssh/authorized_keys2 to 640
```

Comment: ok, wait I am doing that. Second steps are for master or slave machine or both?

Comment: no typo... check also that the hostname that appears in the last line of the .pub file (ex: user@ **jamb-host** ) is known by the naveen host

Comment: Tell me one more thing, when I make passwordless ssh connection, then I run PVM code on my network, it asks for password. I didn't understand why. Can you give me the reason of the same.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873479/adding-slave-in-pvm-asks-for-password

Answer (score 0):

Does naveen have the right to read that file? Also try to editing authorized_keys so the key doesn't have the last string in it (the "someone@somwhere" after the key). So instead of having for example this:

> ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABBAABAQC5IA9w8Knc9YFJZHvRiyZHv7XWXjRgCkLMQdj3LG1pDL8N+7g8C3TB7apA8JqmSs+8YyogN5UzIL1mFz4h1kRvmEcJuoSq+s5+X8aVL0V5qXmcN+TDSevELUpkFm/m/d2RuJAC6+1Eih4PbaGQ0tDVjyBWkgQwbmUNstn3YmdIcavm3z9cPVPIdRGzznLmndOxXOkcMFb32ESuc5NMNKNLcKnzbzyHhXS7JoeKGarTlhmmch7icoRivBWZIWBrdITy6KxkZN8ZSEU1jd6F7WQx1qWO0oEMHrEHnGN4wgi1CZuJTMHXzJbfKc1k91ivb8yh/OK6+iydBNFj94yqAwAD myuser@mypc-EasyNote-TE11HC

You should have this:

> ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABBAABAQC5IA9w8Knc9YFJZHvRiyZHv7XWXjRgCkLMQdj3LG1pDL8N+7g8C3TB7apA8JqmSs+8YyogN5UzIL1mFz4h1kRvmEcJuoSq+s5+X8aVL0V5qXmcN+TDSevELUpkFm/m/d2RuJAC6+1Eih4PbaGQ0tDVjyBWkgQwbmUNstn3YmdIcavm3z9cPVPIdRGzznLmndOxXOkcMFb32ESuc5NMNKNLcKnzbzyHhXS7JoeKGarTlhmmch7icoRivBWZIWBrdITy6KxkZN8ZSEU1jd6F7WQx1qWO0oEMHrEHnGN4wgi1CZuJTMHXzJbfKc1k91ivb8yh/OK6+iydBNFj94yqAwAD==

*Edit:
Just a quick info - after adding "==" to the end of the key you can put the computer name back - the double equals sign ends the key and stuff after it is a note to the key (who's key is it etc..)*

Comment: does it work after removing the computer tag form the end of authorized_keys record? also notice the double equals signs

Comment: ya, when I removed master name at the end from authorized_keys, it saved again.

Comment: please explain "it saved again".. what do you mean? btw, how about those double equals?

Comment: when I remove master machine name . Then save that file, it saved.

It didn't remove that equals to

Comment: But does the key work when you try to connect via ssh now? :)

Comment: It asks for the password. I have done all the things that you said to me.

Comment: It worked by using commands of above answer. But , thanks for your efforts and also you took time for me, to give answer. :)

Comment: You're welcome - by the way the first thing that I asked was if the system has the correct permissions :D The most important thing is that it works now anyway ;)