# Adding slave in PVM asks for password

Tags: linux, shell, parallel-processing, distributed-system, pvm

I tried to add slave in master machine. But when it adds it ask for password. That I didn't understand.

**Master** = jhamb

**Slave** = naveen, raja, gaurav

Please solve below error. Looking for your kind response.

**Snapshot of console :-**

[image]

when I try to add any hosts it shows these lines

```
0successful
       HOST             DTID
       ANY NAME         NO SUCH HOST
```

**vim /etc/hosts shows** :-

```
# Do not remove the following line, or various programs
# that require network functionality will fail.

#127.0.0.1  localhost.localdomain localhost

10.40.54.180 gaurav.my.domain                      #node 1 slave
10.40.54.92 naveen.my.domain                       #node 2 slave
10.40.55.31 raja.my.domain                         #node 3 slave
10.40.55.113 localhost.localdomain                 #node 4 master


#::1            localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
```

**EDITED**

I write here, about my work, what I do till now

1. Download pvm3 tar file.
2. Setup all the variables to run PVM.
3. export PVM_RSH=/ur/bin/ssh
4. make passwordless connection between master and slave.
5. Run simple code on single machine, it works.
6. When I tried to add slave on master, by using command 
       `add naveen.my.domain`
   it says the same, as of above image.

I think now it is sufficient information.

**EDIT NO. 2**

when I run `ssh -v naveen@10.40.54.92`, it says,

```
......
.....
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey, password
debug1: Next Authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key:pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0:new [client-session]
debug1: Entering Interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
.......
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add a slave, PVM tries to start `pvmd` on that machine. To do that, it will try to login via `ssh(1)`. So the line "user@host password:" are from ssh.

You can try it yourself:

```
> ssh naveen.my.domain
```

This article explains what you can do to allow ssh login onto a different machine without giving it a password every time *and* without compromising the security of SSH: [3 Steps to Perform SSH Login Without Password Using ssh-keygen & ssh-copy-id](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/)

**EDIT** Here is the important part of the image above:

```
Verifying Local Path to "rsh"
Rsh found in /usr/bin/ssh - O.K.
Testing Rsh/Rhosts Access to Host ...
```

PVM can use `rsh(1)` and `ssh(1)` to login remotely. **Don't every use rsh(1). It's unsecure, brittle and ugly.**

The output suggests that PVM uses `ssh`. You can verify that by looking at the process list while PVM asks for the password: You should see a ssh child process with PVM as the parent.

So for some reason, your password-less SSH setup is broken.

**EDIT 2** Security isn't easy :-) What you need to understand is that there is a software which remembers the password for you. That's the "ssh agent."

When SSH asks you for a password, then there can be many reasons:

1. The ssh agent isn't running
2. Your key isn't loaded in the ssh agent
3. The wrong key is loaded in the ssh agent
4. You made it work and started a new terminal / new process and that new process doesn't "see" the ssh agent.

To check these:

1. Make sure you see a ssh agent running **with your user ID** in the process list.
2. Make sure the correct key is loaded (add it again if in doubt)
3. Make sure that `ssh naveen` works correctly.
4. Try `pvm` in the same console where you tried `ssh naveen`

Comment: I made a passwordless connection. By saving my id_rsa.pub into slaves's authorized_keys. 
But it asks for a password, that I didn't understand.

Comment: it asks for jhamb@naveen.my.domain

Comment: So `ssh naveen` doesn't ask for a password?

Comment: No, it asks for my passphrase

Comment: So you need to fix that. Is `ssh-agent` running? What's the value of `$SSH_AGENT_PID` in the shell where you ran `ssh`?

Comment: @Aoron Digulla Sir : I didn't understand, please explain these in a simple words. I want to start my first master slave code using PVM.

Comment: Actually I set `PVM_RSH=/usr/bin/ssh` thats it shows above image.

Comment: sorry to say, Actually, it asks for passphrase when I type 

`ssh naveen@10.40.54.92`

Comment: Okay. That makes it more simple to debug. Read the article again which I linked above until `ssh` stops asking for a passphrase.

Comment: ya, it stops asking for parsephrase, but it didn't add any slave, by using command `add ANY-NAME-OF-SLAVE`. Help me in that.

Comment: I can only help you when you give me information. Read http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html, specifically http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#symptoms

Comment: I edited the question. Now if it possible please help me, I tried to solve this problem from long time.

Comment: "make passwordless connection between master and slave" doesn't contain a lot of useful information. See my edits of my answer.

Comment: One thing that I didn't understand is that why we use ssh-agent, when I make password-less connection.

Comment: One thing that I didn't understand is that why we use ssh-agent, when I make password-less connection.

and yes I will implement all your instructions, after that I will tell about my progress.

Comment: When you say "password-less connection", then that can mean a) you created a private key without a pass phrase and b) you try to configure ssh not to ask for the pass phrase when you invoke it. For "b)", you need ssh-agent. "a)" might work without the ssh agent but I never use that.

Comment: First, sorry for late reply.
Any good link for "b" method that explains all the steps. 
My second doubt is in my EDIT NO. 2, I think it is all fine , according to your last comment.

Comment: When `ssh` works when you run it from the command line but not when you use it via PVM, then there must be a difference. Try to set `PVM_RSH` to `/usr/bin/ssh -v` (so it will print debug information). If that doesn't work, write a script that contains `/usr/bin/ssh -v "$@"`, make it executable with `chmod +x` and set `PVM_RSH` to this script.